# Where to store settings.xml for maven in docker based GitLab CI setup

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have several maven projects (not multi-modules), that are residing in GitLab. I like to setup the GitLab CI for these projects, so I looked at `gitlab-ci.yml` files on how to do this.

I found https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab, which describes to put the `settings.xml` in the project itself and then refer it in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

But I was wondering, how this is done when having multiple projects that would need this `settings.xml`, as putting it multiple times in the repository seems bad.

Locally I have it in my `.m2` directory, but how and where to put it on the GitLab server for the pipeline ?

Comment: weirdly, when I make a `mvn deploy` as test in GitLab, it fails with ` Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection`. It tries to connect to the artifactory - which is configured in my local settings.xml ?!

Comment: What's your `gitlab-runner` environment? Windows? Linux? Mac? or Docker? (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/)

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk it is on a unix machine with dockers as runner env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mount the host volume via the `config.toml` as the following example: -

```toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 30

[[runners]]
  name = "some-name"
  url = "url/to/gitlab/"
  token = "some-token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "some-maven-image"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["...", "path/to/host/dir:/some/name:rw"]
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

While the `path/to/host/dir` is a path on host machine which contains many files including with `settings.xml`, `settings-security.xml` and so on, based on project requirement. On the other hand the `/some/name` is a directory inside the docker.

At the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I provide the `before_script` as the following example: -

```
before_script:
  - cp -f /some/name/settings.xml  $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
  - cp -f /some/name/settings-security.xml $HOME/.m2/settings-security.xml
  - ...
after_script:
  - rm -f $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
  - rm -f $HOME/.m2/settings-security.xml
  - ...
```

Please visit [Advanced configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) for further information about the `config.toml`.